# 911 How can I resize this without aspect ratio

Tags: php, image, gd

How can I resize $image_2 & $iamge_3 To be 350x350 without aspect ratio.

I want it to fits two transparency space made 350x350.

```
            <?php
            $imageFile = base_url('upload/users/images/').image_to_thumb($user->image); // 133 x 133
            $watermarkFile = base_url('upload/users/images/').image_to_thumb($user->image); // 133 x 133
            $bgFile = base_url('/backgroundtest.png'); // 93 x 93
            // We want our final image to be 76x76 size
            $x = 1200;
            $y = 630;
            
            // dimensions of the final image
            $final_img = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);

            // Create our image resources from the files
            
            $image_1 = imagecreatefrompng($imageFile);
            $image_2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($watermarkFile);
            $image_3 = imagecreatefrompng($bgFile);
            // Enable blend mode and save full alpha channel
            imagealphablending($final_img, true);
            imagesavealpha($final_img, true);
            
            imagecopy($final_img, $image_1, 200, 200, 0, 0, 350, 350);
            imagecopy($final_img, $image_2, 200, 200, 0, 0, 350, 350);
            imagecopy($final_img, $image_3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1200, 630);

            imagepng($final_img, encode_id($user->id).'.png');
            ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used This and works well.

> [Issue with imagecopy resized PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248838/issue-with-imagecopy-resized-php)

```
$file = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];

$maxW = $maxH = 400;
list($srcW, $srcH) = getimagesize($file);
$ratio = $srcW / $srcH;

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($maxW, $maxH);

if ($ratio > 1) {
    // landscape.
    $destH = ($maxH / $ratio);
    imagecopyresized($dest, $src, 0, ($maxH / 2) - ($destH / 2), 0, 0, $maxW, $destH, $srcW, $srcH);
} else {
    // portrait (or square).
    $destW = ($maxW * $ratio);
    imagecopyresized($dest, $src, ($maxW / 2) - ($destW / 2), 0, 0, 0, $destW, $maxH, $srcW, $srcH);
}
// now do whatever you want with $dest...
```